# JQuery fade effect doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a JQuery slider which works fine in all browsers except IE(always a headache).

Its having a fade transition between 3 layers but that effect wouldn't work on IE. In IE layers just changing without that effect I have shown my JQuery scripts below.

Here is the JSFiddle so that you will get a clear idea.. http://jsfiddle.net/akhilpaul/CsQCK/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
</script>
```

Suggest your opinions about this IE bug..

Paul.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? I don't see anything happening in any browser and clicking the numbers doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Yes you're right I think it should work only by adding this JQuery to the JSFiddle.."jquery-ui.min.js", unfortunately I dont know how to include this..

Comment: There's a checkbox to mark jQuery UI but that does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Jeroen, Yes I saw that, I'm not sure about that anyway.. My slider is working fine on my local server but the only problem is the fade-in effect(from one slide to another) doesn't work in IE..

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark, but you are using relatively old versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

I would suggest to change these to the most recent versions and see if that solves the problem.